# Which Google Maps Option Should I Choose?

Tags: javascript, web-services, web-applications, google-maps

I'm currently working on a location-based app and I'm not sure whether I should use the Google Maps API for Javascript or the Google Places Web Service. For argument's sake, assume that both are technically feasible within the context of my app. Given that, what are the pros/cons of each? Is there a reason to use one over the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is what your talking about (for the web service portion) http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/.

It appears that the Google Places API is meant to be used in addition to, but not exclusive of, the Google Maps API.

> **Usage Limits**
>
> Note: the Places API may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map; using Place data without displaying a map for which Place data was requested is prohibited. Additionally, calculation of Place information may generate copyrights, warnings and/or advertising which must be displayed to the user in some fashion.

So I'm not sure you can use one without the other.